# How to add text in document.write() function when used with onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code document.write() function is not able to take string as its argument,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem seems to be that there are already quotations around `"document.write(5 + 6)"`.

So how do I add a usual text string to it?

Comment: String should be in `single-quotes`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/f3btxg8j/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with single quotes for string as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.write('Hello world')">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may better use `document.getElementById`, because `document.write` is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

```html
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<p id="result"></p>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=5 + 6">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this - let the string be in single quotes.

onclick="document.write(**'5 + 6'**)"

Note: You can interchnage single and double quotes. This also works

**onclick='document.write("5 + 6")'**

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick='document.write(5 + 6)'>Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```